# Browser does not update AJAX form completely

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, crud

I followed this tutorial on [Creating a 100% ajax CRUD using rails 3 and unobtrusive javascript](http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript) - which by the way is a brilliant concept.

However, I realized after updating a post, the form clears quite alright but the button on the form remains "Update post". Since the update is done and the index is rendered, I assumed the button would return to "Create Post".

I tried using `$("input[type='submit']").text("Create post");` to force this behaviour. But this does not change the button. Interestingly, although the button still says "Update post", inspecting the HTML source shows...

```
<input type="submit" value="Update Post" name="commit" style="display: inline-block;">Create post</input>
```

This behaviour is in Chrome and Firefox - all up to date.

Please help explain the cause and hints to fixing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `text()` method, use `val()` :

```
$("input[type='submit']").val("Create post");
```